# Why my function open url but by value is undefined?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, function, undefined

```
                   <asp:TemplateColumn HeaderText="規格管理">
                        <ItemStyle VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <Label runat="server" style="cursor:pointer;color:blue" onclick ="fnOpenURL(this);"  MatAttributeID='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.Attribute_NO") %>'  id="Label2"> 規格 </Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle Wrap="False"></FooterStyle>
                    </asp:TemplateColumn>
```

JS

```
function fnOpenURL(obj)
        {
            offsetWidth="400";
            offsetHeight="450";
            offsetTop=(screen.availHeight-offsetHeight)/2;
            offsetLeft=(screen.availWidth-offsetWidth)/2;
            var tempMiddleCode = '<%=tempMatMiddleClassCode%>';

            var tempURL = "BM1023.aspx?BigMatClassNO=<%=tempMaxClassCode%>&MiddleMatClassNO=" + tempMiddleCode + "&MatAttributeID=" + obj.MatAttributeID;
            window.open(tempURL,"_new","height="+offsetHeight+",width="+offsetWidth+",status=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,status=no,titlebar=no,align=center,left="+offsetLeft+",top="+offsetTop);
        }
```

Then I get "&MatAttributeID=" + obj.MatAttributeID; is undefined
but I see on F12 is matattributeid="1"

and sorry my english is not good

Comment: html attributes are always lower case - use `obj.matattributeid` in the code

Comment: thank you I already try this method but it still undefined

Comment: Sorry, you'll need to use `obj.getAttribute("matattributeid")` - my mistake